# Get selected option in select in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an event

```
'change select': function( event, template ) {
  let role = $( event.target ).find( 'option:selected' ).val();

  [...]
},
```

But couldn't I replace the jQuery code `$( event.target ).find( 'option:selected' ).val()` with plain JS code `event.target.value` and obtain the same result?

So is the above snippet equivalent with

```
'change select': function( event, template ) {
  let role = event.target.value;

  [...]
},
```

and isn't it better to not rely on the jQuery library?

Comment: If you're sure that `event.target.value` (or even just `this.value`) will work with all the browser you require support for, go for it. Using `$(this).val()` will mean that jQuery handles any browser peculiarities for you, such as in `multiple` select boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/xLbeqxws/

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle to see what element fire the event and the structure of the elements?